# Python pop function starts over indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing, logic

I'm trying to remove all instances from a list, for example 9.

I have an ordered list:

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
arg = 9
```

I use `bisect_left(num, 9)`, this returns 8 (the first 9 in list). bisect_left uses binary search to return the left most index where a specific value would be placed.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
arg = 9
index = bisect_left(num, arg)
while(True):
    if(num[index] == arg):
        num.pop(num[index])
        print(num)
        print(num[index])
        print(arg)
    else:
        break
```

When I run this code whilst debugging I print the list.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Of course if I try an do -1 from the index it doesn't pop anything as it's looking at the 7th and comparing it to my argument.

When debugging on the 5th increment of the loop it for some reason pops the 9th index instead.

Whilst further debugging I print `num[index]` and it prints 9 every time.

I'm receiving the error 'num.pop(num[index])
IndexError: pop index out of range'

Comment: This is not a complete code example.  What is `bisect_left()`?  That function is not defined.  Where is the `print()` statement that prints the list?  It matters a lot **exactly where** you put that print statement.

Comment: It's your job to give us a **complete** code example that we can run ourselves, and see the exact same output that you see.

Comment: If you bias the list values by a hundred, you will have an easier time seeing the distinction between "index" and "value": `l = [x + 100  for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]`

Comment: @JohnGordon Hey John, I've added the entire code which you can paste.

Comment: Is the list always ordered?

Comment: @Pingu Yes, it will always be ordered. Although this is test data for readability. The normal data will be 70,000+ items this is why I wanted to use binary search.

Comment: Why make it so hard in the example? Can you just use a simple List Comprehension here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.pop` accepts the index to remove as its argument, not the value.

```py
num.pop(index)
```

Note that you should change the loop condition to ensure that the index does not go out of bounds. Alternatively, consider using `range` instead.

```py
while index < len(num):
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I'm receiving the same error + outputs.

Comment: @OttoLuck Are you sure? It works fine here (no errors and different output): https://ideone.com/EM5pA8

Comment: this works perfectly after rechecking, completely missed this indexing issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than repeatedly modifying the list *in situ* (pop) you could find the low boundary using bisect_left then the high boundary using bisect_right. Consequently slice the original list in two parts to make a new version. For example:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
arg = 9
lo = bisect_left(num, arg)
hi = bisect_right(num, arg)
num = num[:lo]+num[hi:]
print(num)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bisect is a good idea for a sorted list.  You could push it to the limit and get the whole range to remove by using both bisect_left and bisect_right:

```
from bisect import bisect_left,bisect_right

num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
arg = 9

start,end = bisect_left(num,arg),bisect_right(num,arg)
num[start:end] = []

print(num)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```